# How to purge emails without using Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I was handed a bounce email server that went ignored for a while, it now has over 1 million emails, so if I try to Delete All, it will just move them to the deleted folder, which will crash Outlook (I tried it once when it was around 700k emails).

**How do I delete all these emails without using Outlook 2010?** Is there a folder they're stored in that I can purge? Is there another way around this?

Comment: Delete the mailbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do to the following:

1. Open Outlook, **right**-click your *Inbox* and select **Properties**.
2. Open **AutoArchive** tab and set *Archive this folder using these settings* check.
3. Set *Clean out items older than* **1 Days**.
4. Set *Permanently delete old items* check.
5. Click **OK**.
6. Exit Outlook.

Now AutoArchive will hopefully delete all items in your Inbox older than 1 day.

One more way:

1. Open Outlook **right**-click your *Inbox* and select **Delete All** while holding **Shift** key down.
2. Confirm deletion.

Another way:

1. Download Microsoft's [MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com) tool.
2. Run the tool, open Session -> Logon and logon to your profile.
3. Double-click the storage with millions of mails and follow the Root -> IPM_SUBTREE -> Inbox.
4. Right-click the Inbox and select Advanced -> Empty items and subfolders from folder.
5. Optional, only for Exchange Server account: set **Hard Deletion** check and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your request but surely highlighting all the emails within outlook and then using **Shift+Delete** will simply delete them all without the emails going to your deleted items folder.

Comment: There are literally One Million emails in the inbox. I can't even open the inbox without it crashing, let alone selecting all the emails.

Comment: Do you have access to the exchange server?

Comment: No, this is just a mailbox on an unrelated server.

Comment: Do a search for "*.dbx" do you see any inbox stores? If not try Windows+R and type in %appdata% - Then browse to \Identities\[String]\Microsoft\Outlook. (Make sure you've got "show system/hidden files turned on)